# How can to run .sql-file from other .sql-file in MS SQL Database (Microsoft SQL Server)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, mssql-jdbc

I have some .sql-files with creates tables (MS SQL Database):

table_1.sql:

```
IF OBJECT_ID (N'my_schema.table1', N'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE my_schema.table1;

CREATE TABLE my_schema.table1(
  id int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  nameTable1 varchar(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
```

and table_2.sql:

```
IF OBJECT_ID (N'my_schema.table2', N'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE my_schema.table2;

CREATE TABLE my_schema.table2(
 id int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
 nameTable2 varchar(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
```

so, and I want run these two .sql-files in third file: run_all_tables.sql,
How can to run table_1.sql and table_2.sql via run_all_tables.sql, I think it should be similar:

run_all_tables.sql:

```
BEGIN;
\i table_1.sql
\i table_2.sql
COMMIT;
```

What must be in run_all_tables.sql for to run table_1.sql and table_2.sql?  If you have MS SQL Database (Microsoft SQL Server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `SQLCMD` to execute .sql files sequentially.  Putting the files in a single folder called Scripts, you would create the run_all_tables.sql file like so:

```
PRINT 'CREATING TABLES'

:r c:\Scripts\table_1.sql
:r c:\Scripts\table_2.sql

PRINT 'TABLE CREATION IS COMPLETE'
```

After creating that, you call it from command line, connecting to the database server.

```
SQLCMD -S Servername\Instancename -d DatabaseName -i c:\Scripts\run_all_tables.sql
```